# BLINK installation failed in my local python environment in Windows OS

Tags: python, facebook, package, entity-linking

I am facing difficulties to install & use BLINK (Facebook's Entity Linking python library) in my local python environment in Windows OS. Below is detailed error. Any help on this is much appreciated !!!

---

```
(blink371) C:\Users\XXXXXXX\src\blink>pip install -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/BLINK.git#egg=BLINK
Obtaining BLINK from git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/BLINK.git#egg=BLINK
  Updating c:\users\0394d9744\src\blink\src\blink clone
  Running command git fetch -q --tags
  Running command git reset --hard -q 5fe254dd64d37332347edc73738edcb56096183f
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['elq', 'img', 'blink', 'elq_slurm_scripts'].

      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.

      If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
      on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
      Instead, consider the following options:

      1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
      2. use a `src-layout`
      3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

      To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

---

1.Created conda environment and install requirements using below lines of code in CMD:

```
conda create -n blink37 -y python=3.7 && conda activate blink37
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

2. Downloaded the BLINK models using:
   `pip install -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/BLINK.git#egg=BLINK`

Followed above instructions as provided in `README.md` file of below github page of BLINK along with its resolved issues:

[https://github.com/facebookresearch/BLINK](https://stackoverflow.com)